# where to update classpath variable

Tags: java, serial-port, classpath

where to update the classspath ??
i downloaded CommAPI so that import javax.comm.*; should not give error.

Answer (score 1):

You can update it in:

- CLASSPATH environment variable
- -classpath commandline option to java

Comment: what to add in environment variables

Comment: the path to you class/jar file which you are importing and making use of

Comment: i added the path by right clicking on the project name and locating the jar file....n now the error seems to have solved!!

Comment: thnx...Merry Xmas.
Could you suggest me with some small programs where from i can start using functions to read derial port...not much complex programs to start with please...

Comment: You'll find this link of help: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java#Reading_of_Data